# How to get a multiple result in mongoose and combine it in one single response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In a API(Route) call, I wish to have 3 mongoose query and then combine results to form a response json.

**Query**

```
student
  .countDocuments
  (
    {}
  )
  .then(stundentNumber => {
    return stundentNumber
  })

teacher
  .countDocuments
  (
    {}
  )
  .then(teacherNumber => {
    return teacherNumber;
  })

staff
  .countDocuments
  (
    {}
  )
  .then(staffNumber => {
    return staffNumber;
  });
```

**Desired Response**

```
res.json({
    teacher: teacherNumber,
    student: stundentNumber,
    staff: staffNumber
});
```

How can it be done using nodejs/mongoose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `async-await`'s then try as like below where [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will help you to execute all operations in parallel :

```
async function getCounts() {
    let [student,teacher,staff] = await Promise.all([student.countDocuments({}),teacher.countDocuments({}),staff.countDocuments({})]);
    return {student,teacher,staff};
}

/** call this function in main handler function where you get API call */
getCounts().then((data)=>{res.json(data)}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I am looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You must build student,teacher and staff model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
{Schema} = mongoose,
  studentSchema = new Schema(
    {
      name: {
        first: {
          type: String,
          trim: true
        },
        last: {
          type: String,
          trim: true
        }
      },
      studentNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
      },
    }
```

Same model for the other two.
After that,you must write function query. Read more about [queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Comment: I mean total number of records in those collections.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments

Comment: I know how to make a count documents...but I am looking for to combine the results for response.