# NodeJS Promise.all for DB requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

how to make several requests to DB, wait for results from all requests and return results?
I try with Promise.all, but all I get - [undefined] in console.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("DBusers");
    var query = {};
    var U4 = dbo.collection("users");  
    const promises = [
        U4.find({}).count(function (err, result) { return result; }),
        U4.find({}).count(function (err, result) { return result; })
    ];

    Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    db.close();


});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a multiple result in mongoose and combine it in one single response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841373/how-to-get-a-multiple-result-in-mongoose-and-combine-it-in-one-single-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer, 
I had to change to:

```
const promises = [
            U4.find({}).count(),
            U4.find({}).count()
];
```

Comment: you can use the following code to make multiple requests to your DB (when you define them in promises). When all requests finished, you can return them, or send to your frontend for example.

Answer (score 2):

you use a callback function to `Promise.all` array. it's correct way to use `Promise.all`:

```
const promises = [
    U4.find({}).count(),
    U4.find({}).count()
];
```

by default that returns a promise and you must be past array of promise to `Promise.all`.